# versioned symbols with Linux ld-linux.so

Tags: linux, gcc, ld

I am trying to understand how ld-linux.so resolves references to versioned symbols on Linux. I have the following files:

test.c:

```
void f();

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

a.c and b.c:

```
void f() {}
```

symbols.txt:

```
ABC {
    global:
        *;
};
```

Makefile:

```
all: liba.so libb.so test

liba.so: a.c
    gcc -g -shared $^ -o $@ -Wl,--version-script=symbols.txt

libb.so: b.c
    gcc -g -shared $^ -o $@

test: test.c liba.so
    gcc -g test.c -la -L. -o $@

clean:
    rm -f liba.so libb.so test
```

I then ran the following command

```
LD_PRELOAD=./libb.so LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./test
```

I find that *f()* from b.c is invoked even though the symbol *f* in libb.so does not have the version required by *test* (*f@ABC*). Why does this happen ?

Answer (score 0):

version-script is used to confine the symbols to be exported in shared libraries. this means faster link speed and few change for symbols conflict.

By default, most function name will be exported, so you can link with libb.so without any problem.

If you want to determine which version of function should be used, You need to specify it in your program. This need some assembly code to specify .symver.

For more details, please read Ulrich Drepper’s paper https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf